# Automatically start debugger server when ZeroBrane starts

Tags: zerobrane

How to make ZeroBrane to automatically initiate the debugger server on startup?

I have embedded Lua in a C++ application.  I would like to debug the Lua scripts using ZeroBrane.  The C++ application launches ZeroBrane, call mobdebug.start(), but then the user has to go to Project->Start Debugger Server manually.  Can ZeroBrane be configured so that it starts the server when the IDE launches?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I think I solved it.  I just added:

```
local debugger = ide:GetDebugger()
debugger:Listen(true)
```

inside the `postinit = function ()` in the zbstudio/app.lua file.

Comment: you don't need to modify zbstudio/app.lua as it's going to be overwritten on the next update; you can use [AutostartDebugger](https://github.com/pkulchenko/ZeroBranePackage/blob/master/autostartdebug.lua) plugin to do this.